# Need to add a custom type and use a prototype property within my form

Tags: javascript, html, methods, prototype, custom-type

I am trying to create a custom type and then add a method to the custom type using its prototype property within the dummy form I have created. I am trying to wrap my mind around how I could create a custom type that would essentially create a "new subscriber." I am having problems figuring out how to do this. I am still very new with JavaScript and this syntax is beyond me. The documentation per the MDN is just confusing me, so I decided to seek some help. I have created a JSfiddle and I would appreciate any and all help from the community.

```
www.jsfiddle.net/cbadrew00/ex67bbsj/11/
```

Thank you kindly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create custom types by creating functions that will "construct" properties on new objects, like so:

```
function User(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

The `this` reference in `User` is the new object instance, which is created by using `new`.

Then you construct the object using:

```
var user = new User("John", "john@somwhere.com");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ex67bbsj/13/

Comment: Thank you for this. I understand whats going on with the syntax and this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor and try to create private versions of the variables:

```
var Subscriber = function (name, email) {
    var _name  = name,
        _email = email,
        self   = this; // This is used so we can get the name and email variables

    this.name  = _name;
    this.email = _email;

    //To add functions, use this.FunctionName = function () {

    this.validate = function () {
        if (_name == '') {
            alert('Enter a name');
            return false; // Saying that it is invalid
        }
        if (_email == '') {
            alert('Enter an email');
            return false; // Saying that it is invalid
        }

        return true;
    };

    this.send = function () {
        if (self.validate()) { //Validates it
            alert('You are now a subscriber!');
        }
    };
};
```

then use it like:

```
var subscriber = new Subscriber('Phil', 'phil@philscompany.com');
subscriber.send();
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/87h17azd/2/)

---

This adds a type, `Subscriber`. You can add functions using `this.functionName`.